# Mutual Index of Coincidence

Tags: algorithm, math, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm currently attempting to solve a Caesar Cipher without knowing a key. I am to approach the problem using a mutual index of coincidence to determine what is the key. I have solved the problem with other methods using statistical properties of English but I'd like to attempt the problem using this method as well.

I just found out that index of coincidence and mutual index of coincidence are two different things. Given a mono-alphabetic cipher, the index of coincidence will always return a ~0.067 (for english). However, it does not seem to be the case from what I was given.

I'd need some help on understanding how to craft the algorithm for identifying the mutual index of coincidence given the formula

[image: MIC Formula]

Given that [image] where [image: fi] is the occurrence of the ith letter in the alphabet and N is the length of text and [image: qi+k]

From what I have understood (I'm terrible at Math), I have to iterate through an i of 0-25 and get the index of max mutual index of coincidence among the 25 and that will give me the key for the cipher. In order to do that, I have to multiply pi with qi+k. However, if pi is roughly equal to qi+k for all i, does it not mean that [image: pi]? With that, isn't the equation a summation of squared pi?

Comment: I assume p_i is the expected frequency of letters (given by frequency analysis of English text). I think you've missed some words out. I suppose the original text says that you have to find k (from 0 to 25) such that each p_i is roughly equal to q_{i+k} for each i. The "mutual index of coincidence" is one measure of how close two vectors are (essentially equivalent to cosine similarity), so the k with the highest MIC is a good candidate for the original key.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right about finding k (0-25) such that each p_i is roughly eq to q_{i+k} for each i, though the question just stated all i. I'm not sure if I'm missing out anymore details from the question (hopefully not), but I am a little stuck on how to start on getting the MIC for each k.

Comment: What's your specific problem? Have you computed the 26 frequencies q[i]? Do you have (I guess English) letter frequencies p[i]?

Comment: In my code, I have managed to get letter frequencies on all characters for each key from 0 to 25. But I am not sure on how do I obtain the MIC from there. I assumed that p_i q_{i+k} meant (f_{i+k} / N) * (f_{i+k} /N) summed but I realised they're the same thing (and doesn't give me a close MIC anyways) so I must have been wrong trying to create the formula to calculate the MIC for each k.

Comment: Hmm, p[i] should be a vector that looks something like [0.082, 0.014, 0.028, ...] (letter frequencies for English from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language). q[i] should be a vector that stores the observed frequency of each letter in the cyphertext, divided by the length of the cyphertextt.

Comment: The MIC[k] is `sum(p[i] * q[(i+k)%26] for i in range(26))` in python.

Comment: The formula provided is correct, thank you so much! @PaulHankin

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Paul Hankin for clarification. The p_i in this case was actually not q_{i+k} but rather the probability of occurrence of each letter in the English language (which is fixed) and q_{i+k} refers to the occurrence of each letter shifted with the key in the ciphertext.

The solution provided by Paul where MIC[k] is sum(p[i] * q[(i+k)%26] for i in range(26)) is correct - the result from the equation will have to be divided by N to obtain the mutual index of coincidence.